# Login in facebook, from PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm interested in, if its possible, to log in on Facebook from another website.

For example : On the website is a form asking for an e-mail address and password.

Someone submits it; Is it possible to redirect to fb and log in?

Comment: yes I googled it. and results were login on web-site with fb account

Comment: The only way to login users is using facebook provided tools, like dialogs, login button, redirect user to facebook then redirect it back to your app, etc. I advise you to read the facebook documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so because in the first step a request token of some sort is to be received from the Facebook servers. After this your server would have access to the login page (on the Facebook side) and only then the user can log in with his username and password.